# Spliting the string in SQL Server using a delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

My string is as below :

```
<SL1> Locationdetails are in the table .<RXCH><cF7712>Location1<cF4712>
        <RXCS1>H1<RXCS2>H2<RXCS3>H3
        <RXC11>C11<RXC12>C12
        <RXC13>C13<RXC21>C21
        <RXC22>C22<RXC23>C23
        <RXC31>C31<RXC32>C32
        <RXC33>C33<RXC41>C41
        <RXC42>C42<RXC43>C43
        <RXC51>C51<RXC52>C52
        <RXC53>C53
        <RXCH><cF7712>Location1<cF4712>
        <RXCS1>H1<RXCS2>H2<RXCS3>H3
        <RXC11>C11<RXC12>C12
        <RXC13>C13<RXC21>C21
        <RXC22>C22<RXC23>C23
        <RXC31>C31<RXC32>C32
        <RXC33>C33<RXC41>C41
        <RXC42>C42<RXC43>C43
        <RXC51>C51<RXC52>C52
        <RXC53>C53. Services for primary health care'
```

I would like to split the above string and the output as below:

OUTPUT should be:

```
'Location1 H1 H2 H3 C11 C12 C13 C21 C22 C23 C31 C32 C33 C41 C42 C43 C51 C52 C53 Location1 H1 H2 H3 C11 C12 C13 C21 C22 C23 C31 C32 C33 C41 C42 C43 C51 C52 C53'
```

Comment: Do you have some draft versions of a query? How did you get such a strange string format?

Comment: The biggest problem you have here is that you have no consistent delimiter and it's malformed XML. If it were well formed XML you could probably achieve what you want with xpath queries. As it is the easiest thing I can think of (and it's not that straightforward) is to use RegEx but in order to do that you need a .Net assembly to make things simple. I have an example of exactly that but it's at home and I'm not. If this is still unanswered tonight I'll write it up and post it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Get text between points
set @str = stuff (@str, 1, charindex ('.', @str), '')
set @str = left (@str, charindex ('.', @str) - 1)
-- Get rid of spaces, tabs and line ends
set @str = replace (replace (replace (replace (@str, ' ', ''), char(9), ''), char(10), ''), char(13), '')
-- Output
select ltrim (cast(replace (@str, '>', '/> ') as xml).value('.', 'varchar(max)'))
```

Comment: That'll do it! I was looking for a solution that was too complicated. I like the way you simply made all the tags self closing and queried that. Never even crossed my mind to do that.